# split strings on punctuation except for tags

Tags: python, regex, string, split

How do I split a string on any punctuations and blank space except for # character?

```
tweet="I went on #Russia to see the world cup. We lost!"
```

I would like to split the string below like this:

```
["I", "went", "to", "#Russia", "to, "see", "the", "world", "cup", "We","lost"]
```

My attempt:

```
p = re.compile(r"\w+|[^\w\s]", re.UNICODE)
```

Does not work since it creates "Russia" instead of "#Russia"

Comment: what about split function in python ?

Comment: but i would need to repeat the split command for each punctuaction mark.... Isn't a regex much faster?

Comment: It does not look like you are tokenizing the strings (the regex you are using tokenizes a string, but the expected output does not resemble a tokenized string). Are you extracting letter words  that may have `#` in front? Try just `re.findall(r'#?\b[^\W\d_]+\b', s)`

Comment: If you also need to match digits and `_`, you may plainly use `re.findall(r'#?\b\w+\b', s)`. Are you using Python 2.x, BTW?

Answer (score 3):

Just include the '#'

```
p = re.compile(r"[\w#]+", re.UNICODE)
```

Comment: Note this may be too "greedy", e.g. with strings like `#Russia#football`. Also, `re.UNICODE` is only needed in Python 2.x, as in Python 3.x it is a default behavior.

Answer (score 2):

With `re.findall` function:

```
tweet="I went on #Russia to see the world cup. We lost!"
words = re.findall(r'[\w#]+', tweet)
print(words)
```

The output:

```
['I', 'went', 'on', '#Russia', 'to', 'see', 'the', 'world', 'cup', 'We', 'lost']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `re.sub`

**Ex:**

```
import re
tweet="I went on #Russia to see the world cup. We lost!"
res = list(map(lambda x: re.sub("[^\w#]", "", x), tweet.split()))
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
['I', 'went', 'on', '#Russia', 'to', 'see', 'the', 'world', 'cup', 'We', 'lost']
```